# how to resolve "system repair pending" in Win7

Tags: windows-7, boot, sfc

My PC running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit suddenly fails to boot normally. I'm able to boot into Safe Mode w/ Networking, but I can't boot normally even after using `msconfig.exe` to disable *everything*. I've tried booting from the last good configuration, but that failed in exactly the same way. I disabled System Restore a long time ago so there are no restore points. I've run Malwarebytes and it didn't find anything. I've had AVG installed since day 1 and haven't had any trouble with viruses since building it. `chkdsk /f` reports no errors.

When I attempt to run Startup Repair, it says that it can't repair the computer automatically. Problem details:

```
Problem Event Name: StartupRepairOffline
Problem Signature 01: 6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 02: 6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 03: unknown
Problem Signature 04: 21200512
Problem Signature 05: ManualRepair
Problem Signature 06: 2
Problem Signature 07: NoBootFailure
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID: 1033
```

I let Startup Repair run several times, and eventually I found this in the diagnostic and repair details:

```
Root cause found:
---------
Unspecified changes to system configuration might have caused the problem.

Repair action: System files integrity check and repair
Result: Failed. Error code = 0x490
Time taken = 124661 ms
```

(The net says that `0x490` signals a bad boot sector. I've already run `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /fixmbr`, both of which complete "successfully," but the problem persists.)

I decide to run `sfc` to fix corrupt system files. However, it fails, saying that there is a system repair pending. This seems to be confirmed by the fact that `C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml` has a lot of content (it looks like a couple hundred lines). I have read elsewhere that interfering with the repair process (e.g. deleting pending.xml) can leave the OS damaged beyond repair, and I wish to avoid reinstalling.

How do I get rid of this pending system repair so that `sfc` can run?

Comment: boot into the recovery options (CMD.exe) and run this command: **DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions**

Comment: @magicandre1981: I assume you mean "D:\", to refer to the disk with the OS?

Comment: jep. have you tried it?

Comment: @magicandre1981: I did, and I updated my post. It looked like it worked (pending.xml is gone), but `sfc /scannow` still says there's a repair pending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "system repair pending" message can be caused by at least two very different things:

1. There is actually a system repair in-progress, which must be completed or rolled back before running `sfc`.
2. `sfc` is attempting to fix system files on the wrong drive.

In my case, both problems applied.

I had to address problem #2 first. The correct command is:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=X:\ /offwindir=Y:\Windows
```

Where:

- `X` is the system volume (often named "System Reserved")
- `Y` is the volume where Windows is installed

[You need to use `diskpart` to figure out what the correct letters are](http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-perform-offline-system-integrity.html). Even if Windows is normally installed on `C:\` (which it often is), drive letters can be assigned differently in the Windows Recovery Environment (WRE).

From the command prompt in the WRE:

```
> diskpart
DISKPART > list volume

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type         Size     Status     Info   
----------  ---  -----------  -----  -----------  -------  ---------  -------
Volume 0    C    Old Games    NTFS   Partition     465 GB  Healthy           
Volume 1    D                 NTFS   Partition      59 GB  Healthy           
Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition     100 MB  Healthy    Hidden 
Volume 3    E    Storage      NTFS   Partition     931 GB  Healthy           
Volume 4    F    Games        NTFS   Partition     476 GB  Healthy           
Volume 5    G    Traffic      NTFS   Partition     297 GB  Healthy
```

Based on their sizes, I recognize Volume 1 as the primary volume where Windows is installed (aka my usual `C:` drive, a 60 GB SSD), and Volume 2 as the system boot volume (which is often labeled "System Reserved," and is apparently always 100 MB). Importantly, Volume 2 doesn't have a drive letter, which means we can't refer to it in the `sfc` command. We can assign a drive letter like so:

```
DISKPART > select volume 2
DISKPART > assign letter=b:

# now that we're done, exit back to DOS
DISKPART > exit
```

Now we're ready to run `sfc` with the correct values:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=B:\ /offwindir=D:\windows\
```

At this point, I still receive the "system repair pending" error, so we need to use `dism` to resolve it. The command is:

```
dism /image:X:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

Where `X` is the volume where Windows is installed. We already know that's `D:`, so we can run:

```
dism /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

For `dism` to finish the job, you have to reboot.

While this didn't fix my boot issues, it did allow `sfc` to run.

**NOTE**: Again, drive letters being different in the WRE can interfere with `sfc` logging, which attempts to log to `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`. If, like me, your Windows volume isn't assigned to `C:` in the WRE, you can temporarily override the log path with this command:

```
> set WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE=D:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
```

(Again using a drive letter chosen by consulting `diskpart`.)

The effect of this command only lasts until you exit the command prompt. Also, `sfc` *will not create any directories for you*, so if you decide to store the logs somewhere else, e.g. `C:\i_just_made_this_folder_up\mylog.txt`, you need to manually create the `i_just_made_this_folder_up` folder *before* running `sfc`.

Comment: I should mention that only in hindsight did it become clear to me that I had to address problem #2 first. I wasn't aware the "pending repair" message I was seeing could be caused by targeting the wrong drive, and it doesn't seem to be widely known. By the time I learned that, I had already run the `dism` command (with the correct drive letter) to roll back the pending repair operation. Regardless, running through this process in the order I describe ought to work for anyone, no matter which of the two issues applies to them.

Comment: precisely answered. I just catch the same situation on an old machine, this answer worked perfectly. That problem occurred because the drive letters are changed on the recovery ambient (but windows worgly was reporting as pending action, when there was none pending).

Answer (score 1):

To cancel the pending operation, you have to [boot into the recovery options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7)

[image]

select `Command Prompt` and run this command:

`DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions`

When you now reboot to the Windows, Windows will remove all pending operations.

Comment: As my original post indicates, I have already tried this. `dism` reported success, but `sfc` still fails. Thanks anyway. 8)

Comment: don't mix all question into 1. you wanted to know how to stop it. I answered this.

Comment: You're right -- I'm combining several questions into one.  I will edit the OP down to focus on reverting the pending action. However, both your comment and answer omit critical information, so I can't mark this as the answer.

Comment: what is missing? you said my command fixed the pending issue and I **SHOULD** post it as answer.

Comment: @Tom -This is an answer to the proposed question.  There is no critical information from this answer.

Comment: @ramhound This answer doesn't mention that the message I'm receiving can be caused by targeting the wrong drive, nor does it describe how to re-target the command at the right one. This answer is likely to fail for anyone who has more than one internal storage device, presumably owing to the mapping of the SATA or IDE ports on the mobo. Perhaps most importantly: running the command from this answer did not fix the problem without my modifying it according to instructions I had to find elsewhere. I sincerely appreciate the effort, but I'm not marking this as the answer.

Comment: I gave it up, you flame because I can't see in my crstal ball that your Windows is drive D:. LOL **facepalm**, in the future I'll ignore you.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Your submission is an inadequate answer because it omits a relevant cause of the error I posted about, one which may apply to others who find this post. If you think your answer is better than mine, you're welcome to direct a moderator here. I hope you rethink your decision to ignore my posts in the future -- your comment ultimately helped me diagnose the problem. But my answer reflects a week of research and experimentation that far surpasses your contribution. I'd like to think you might even learn something from it. You can't win 'em all, friend.